# Query 1 table twice with filters with one result stream without a join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to query a table once as the time to query this table is about 8-12 mins and querying it twice is simply too long. There is a flag in the table for identifying internal vs external results. I want the sum of column A & Sum of B where this flag is internal and the sum of column B & C & D where this flag is external.. right now its two separate queries joined together...

This is an example of the first query

```
Select
CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111) as DatePeriod --weekly
,[Group] as [Group]
,SUM([columnA]) as [columnA_int]
,SUM([columnB]) as [columnB_int]    
from  myTbl
where internal_external = 'internal' 
group by 
CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111),[Group]
```

second query

```
Select
CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111) as DatePeriod --weekly
,[Group] as [Group]
,SUM([columnB]) as [columnB_ext]
,SUM([columnC]) as [columnC_ext]
,SUM([columnC]) as [columnC_ext]        
from  myTbl
where internal_external = 'external' 
group by 
CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111),[Group]
```

so ideally one query all 5 columns and only hit the DB up once.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use DISTICT and combine the wheres with an OR?

Comment: Sorry my SQL skills are quite novice, could you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT
    internal_external
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111) as DatePeriod --weekly
    ,[Group] as [Group]
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN internal_external='internal' THEN [columnA]
            ELSE 0 
          END) as [columnA_int]
    ,SUM([columnB]) as [columnB_intext] 
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN internal_external='external' THEN [columnC]
            ELSE 0 
          END) as [columnC_ext]
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN internal_external='external' THEN [columnC]
            ELSE 0 
          END) as [columnC_ext2]
FROM  myTbl
GROUP BY
    internal_external
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111)
    ,[Group]
-- use the next lines if there are other values for internal_external
HAVING 
    internal_external IN('internal', 'external')
```

Or, if you want to forgo the internal_external column:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111) as DatePeriod --weekly
    ,[Group] as [Group]
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN internal_external='internal' THEN [columnA]
            ELSE 0 
          END) as [columnA_int]
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN internal_external='internal' THEN [columnB]
            ELSE 0 
          END) as [columnB_int]
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN internal_external='external' THEN [columnB]
            ELSE 0 
          END) as [columnB_ext]
    ,SUM(CASE 
            WHEN internal_external='external' THEN [columnC]
            ELSE 0 
          END) as [columnC_ext]
FROM  myTbl
GROUP BY
    internal_external
    ,CONVERT(varchar(10), right([week_name],10), 111)
    ,[Group]
-- use the next lines if there are other values for internal_external
HAVING 
    internal_external IN('internal', 'external')
```

Comment: Because I don't want the sum of columnA to contain the external values? There are internal and external values for columnA and I only want one set, column B also has int/ext but I want it pulled twice with the sum separated. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: changed.  If the columns are not laid out as your like, you will have to explain it in detail.  It cannot be done like your two sample queries because they have different column counts (the column counts and types must match).

Comment: Thanks I will test this out and let you know!

Comment: RBarryYoung I don't want to select Internal_External in the end data piece.

I just want to see for example:
Group 1 A, B_int, B_ext, C is that not possible?

Comment: it is, but it's a lot easier to tell the internal and external rows apart if you have that.  For instance, that way you do not have to have two different B columns, the internal_external column tells you which it is.  but hookay, ...

Comment: Works like a treat thank you :)

Know of a workaround for also including totals by month as well instead of having to do a second query? right now pulls the week but if I could have weeks and month totals as the rows that would be ideal. End state is I pull all this into a pivot and then add in formulas and then reference pivot for our templates! Cheers

Comment: You'd have to add a UNION for that, and then it'd probably try to scan it twice.

Comment: Thought so, that is what I am currently doing and it does scan twice which sucks but better than it scanning 4 times which I was doing prior to your help! Thanks